# Paste from client's clipboard on Shiny Server

Tags: r, clipboard, shiny

I have a simple app, trying to read client clipboard. It is working on my local machine but not on shiny server. Here is my Ui and server functions :

```
library(shiny)
library(clipr)
ui = basicPage(

        dataTableOutput('mytable'),
        actionButton("paste", "Paste")
    )


library(shiny)
library(clipr)
    server = function(input, output) {
        observeEvent(input$paste, {
            output$mytable = renderDataTable({
                        dataSet <- read_clip_tbl(x=read_clip(),
                                                 row.names = NULL,
                                                     sep = "\t",
                                                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
            })
        })
    }
```

The error massage on the server is :

```
Clipboard on X11 requires that the DISPLAY envvar be configured.
```

I have tried to configure display on shiny server by `export DISPLAY=localhost:10.0`, but still this does not fix the problem.
Does anyone knows that even this action is possible in shiny if so, what changes are necessary in my code ?

Comment: I have R version 3.3.3 and your code is working fine in my system for the Shiny also. Sure it is issue with some packages.

Comment: @RahulAgarwal Did you try to deploy it to shiny server and run it then ?  In local machine is working, but when you put it on shiny server, it won't work.